# Filter a layer and edit over that filter in QGIS 2.1.4.1

Tags: qgis

I'm new using QGIS,

I have a layer with the field called "districts"
Classified by district A, B, C, and D

I need to work with District C, I'm doing a filter from District C

But I can not enter the edit option because the layer is filtered.
I wanted to edit attribute table of this layer

Is there a way to work with a filtered layer?

The idea of filtering is because I need to see specifically where the points of district C are located

enter image description here

[image]

This is the complete layer

This is the filter

[image]

Now I want to edit on the filter the attributes table using the field calculator

[image]
But I do not have the option to edit the table either the field

Comment: In 2.14.9 (Linux Mint 18) it works well. Can edit filtered layer. Testing with filtered attributes in attribute table, and olso with applied filter for whole layer (filter option in properties). Do you have write permission to your file/folder containing this file?

Comment: I am using a version of qgis portable.

Do you think that's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience with portable versions of QGIS, so maybe someone else can test it. Did you try it on other data? Just in case, editing works fine without filters?

Comment: I feel OP is talking about "Provider feature filter (Query Builder)" while @OtoKaláb is suggesting Filter on an Attribute Table.

Comment: @Kazuhito I tried both, but maybe I don't describe it clearly enough (filter option in properties = query builder)

Comment: @OtoKaláb oh, I am terribly sorry. You have been clear about that. And I confirm it ( *Properties | General | Provide feature filter | Query Builder* ) is editable in 2.14.9 (Windows). I do not remember if it was editable when I first started to use QGIS, 3-4 months ago... it was 2.14.3/5?

Comment: Can you edit the layer if you remove the filter? If so, instead of filtering it you could use a rule-based symbology to display only the points in district C. Then use the same rule to limit the features that are displayed in the attribute table.